# when to use %do %end vs do end loop in sas

Tags: sas

I am new to the macro world and trying to figure out when to use %do %end vs do end in sas. There are other intricacies apart from using %do %end outside of a datastep. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`do-end` is data step syntax and can only execute within a data step. This is mainly useful for peforming the same logic multiple times per row, e.g. with arrays.

`do-end` can also be used 'vertically' to read in multiple rows at a time from your input data source before outputting a row (a construct known for obscure reasons as a [DOW-loop](http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2010/BB13.Dorfman.pdf)).

`%do-%end` is macro syntax and is only valid within a macro definition, i.e. in between `%macro yourmacroname;` and the corresponding `%mend;` statement. You can use a macro to generate code for multiple separate data steps or procs, or to generate repetitive code within a single data step.

If you're generating repetitive code within a data step, and you have the choice of using either `%do-%end` or `do-end`, it's usually a better idea to stick to `do-end` and avoid using macros, as these add an extra layer of complexity to your code.

Comment: +1 for the DOW-loop reference.  In addition to the use case you mention, it's also useful for making multiple passes across a data set within a single DATA step (e.g. the so-called Double DOW-Loop).  Though I'm not sure the reasons for its name are as obscure as you suggest. :) I always heard it was the "DOrfman-Whitlock Loop" after its two most prominent promoters on SAS-L.

Comment: Wow... never heard of the DOW-loop before.  That's pure awesomeness. I already have some tasks in mind where it should simplify my code.

Comment: @Rob I'm surprised that you haven't come across it already here on SO. I suppose it isn't always explicitly identified as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it within a data-step (horizontally i.e. across row), then use a do-end. If you want to do it outside a data-step (i.e. executing one or more procs over and over), then use a %do-%end.

Though there may be times when you could get away with either given flexible constraints, the above should guide you through getting started.